# Can vim plugins be invoked by external vim arguments

Tags: bash, vim, vim-plugin

I have a bash script that runs Vim in a certain way on multiple files. Is it possible to write a Vim plugin that is invoked by an external argument to Vim itself? For example if I run `vim --something <filename>` I want it to run my plugin and get the filenames as well. Is this possible with Vim plugins?

Thank you

Comment: The best you can do is `vim -c <command>` or `vim --cmd <command>` (Note: there are different, `-c` happens after loading the first file and `--cmd` happens before the vimrc is read). However neither will really get you what you want since the file will be opened normally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample `script.vim` what reads input argument and prints it back in upper case:

```
redir @a
silent exe "%print"
redir END

let var=shellescape(@a)
let var=substitute(var, "\n", "", "")
let var=substitute(var, "\\", "", "")

exe ":!echo -n argument was: " . toupper(var)
```

Here is how you run it:

```
$ echo "hello world" | vim - -es '+:so ./script.vim' '+:q!'
```